# Can you blind a Demilich/creature that has Truesight?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light, blind, special-senses

RAW, I don't see why you can't blind something with *Truesight*, but I feel like it shouldn't be possible. (Maybe vestiges of previous editions?) I wonder whether I've overlooked some basic rule.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Yes, you can *blind* something with *Truesight*.

The only thing *Truesight* does in this case is magnify the ability that was lost to *blindness*:

*Truesight* **enhances** one's ability to see: through magical darkness, invisibility, illusions, shapechanges, and into the Ethereal (PHB p.185).

But the *blindness* condition now says **"you can't see.** The sight through illusions, darkness, &c. which you so enjoyed just a moment ago, you don't **have** anymore (PHB p.290, paraphrased)."

---

In your specific example of the Demilich, note that *blindness* is **not** one of the (many) condition immunities listed in its stat block (MM p.48).

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure if it wasn't listed *because of* True sight (and there was a pertinent background ruling), or because it could actually be blinded.