# Can a blind character benefit from gaining Truesight?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light, blind

If a blind character acquired some way (whether though homebrew classes, blessings or magic items) of gaining blindsight or tremorsense, that character would be able to use those senses without issue. However, would the same be true if said character gained truesight? Is truesight a different sense to your regular vision, or is it a modification to it (and thus a blind character's vision would be modified to allow truesight, but he would still have a vision range of 0ft, rendering the modification useless)?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72157/23970)? Would appreciate others' eyes/thoughts on the matter.

Comment: I think the answer to that question answers this one, at least.

Comment: @nitsua60 Agreed with Mark. The frame of the question is different (can a blind creature see if it is given Truesight vs. Can a creature that can see with Truesight be blinded at all) but I think the answer to the latter actually answers this question to completeness.

Comment: I agree as well.  It just answers the question in reverse, could see and now can't in the other question vs can't see and could it see in this one.

Comment: Okay, with four others weighing in I'll cast my dupe-vote. But if another stackizen comes along and thinks they see daylight, don't be shy about flagging for mod-reopening.

Answer (score 3):

Truesight is described as something that allows someone to "see" things better than common sight. You need sight to see, so probably truesight won't work

> A monster with truesight can, out to a specific range, **see** in normal and magical darkness, **see** invisible creatures and objects, automatically detect **visual** illusions... [*MM Pg 9, emphasys mine*]