# Does Darkvision grant normal Vision

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light

A Transmutation Wizard has decided to make a Transmuter's Stone and has chosen the property of granting Darkvision. What happens when a blind character has this stone in their possession?

Comment: Related, sort of opposite question: [can you blind a creature that has truesight?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72157/23970)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Darkvision is unfortunately useless to a blind person. Weirdly, when a race gets Darkvision, it's described in that race's entry. But the Transmuter's Stone says this:

> Darkvision out to a range of 60 feet, as described in chapter 8

So if we find the entry on Darkvision in chapter 8 (PHB, page 183):

> Within a specified range, a creature with darkvision can see in darkness as if the darkness were dim light, so areas of darkness are only lightly obscured as far as that creature is concerned.

Blind people can't see in dim light<sup>[citation needed]</sup>, so seeing in darkness as if it was dim light doesn't actually help them at all.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out there's no monsters in the Monster Manual with Darkvision that are blind beyond that radius. If such a combination were meaningful, you'd expect it to show up at some point.

Comment: What part does "Weirdly" refer to?

Answer (score 1):

In the rules, being blinded results in the following:

> A blinded creature can’t see and automatically fails any ability check that requires sight.

Therefore, it does not matter if the creature gains Darkvision, because they still can't see, and automatically fail any task involving sight.

Comment: Not very helpful, since you've asserted that the creature still can't see, when the question is about will they be able to see (and therefore lose it's blindness auto-failures)