# Does Warding Flare work against spell attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Warding Flare in 5e says that it induces disadvantage on attacking creatures by throwing up a light between you and the attacker.

Does that include spell attacks or just physical attacks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes... if

> Warding Flare
>
> Also at 1st level, you can interpose divine light between
> yourself and an attacking enemy. When you are attacked
> by a creature within 30 feet of you that you can see,
> you can use your reaction to impose disadvantage on
> the attack roll, causing light to flare before the attacker
> before it hits or misses. An attacker that can’t be blinded
> is immune to this feature.
> You can use this feature a number of times equal to
> your Wisdom modifier (a minimum of once). You regain
> all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

pp 61 of the PHB 5e

So that means that so long as the caster is within 30 feet and can be blinded **and** the spell he/she's casting requires an attack roll.

For example, this effect wouldn't work on a caster casting magic missile or fireball. It also wouldn't work on a caster who has blindsight. It also wouldn't work if the caster were more than 30ft away.

Comment: For completeness; it also doesn't work for spells that allow a saving throw, since those aren't attack rolls. (Your example of Magic Missile has no defense at all, but Fireball also couldn't be blocked for this reason)

Comment: Thanks for that @Erik I've added it to my answer

Comment: To make even more complete, why not add this https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/935622022456938497
to show definitively that attack here means all attacks and not just weapon ones.

Comment: also https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72157/can-you-blind-a-demilich-creature-that-has-truesight may be useful

Answer (score 3):

> When you are attacked by a creature within 30 feet of you
>   that you can see (PHB 61)

As the feature does not specify that it only works against one or the other, it works against both.

Comment: Except that if the magic user is casting magic missile or fireball *they don't have to make an attack roll* - so they don't care it would be at disadvantage.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes, but then it is not a *spell attack* either, which the question already (wisely) specified.