# How can my blind character get temporary sight?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light, blind

My character in D&D 5e Homebrew as I created her, a 2nd-level [pyromancer](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Pyromancer_(5e_Class))  has her eyes burnt out magically. The DM told me that they cannot be returned by any healing spell. (Of course, the *wish* spell could do this, but my current level and funding is much too low for that.)

So I was wondering: Is there any cheap way to return my character's vision, or some of it?

I would like to have some sight overall, maybe for short usage or something like that, but for most part I would like to keep the character blind.

Comment: No worries, and where are our manners; Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your character concept. You want to blind, but you don't want to that fixed via spells. But you want something that gives you vision so you're not blind.

Comment: @jamesb Maybe, but I think Mindaugas Bartkus needs to clarify. But if that's so, there are other ways to potentially handle that as well.

Answer (score 18):

## *Find familar*

The *[find familiar](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Find%20Familiar#content)* spell is not on the sorcerer spell list, so you would either need to take a level in wizard to cast it, or use a *[ring of spell storing](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ring%20of%20Spell%20Storing#content)* or *[ioun stone](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ioun%20Stone#h-Ioun%20Stone) of reserve* to have someone else cast the spell for you. Find familiar allows you to see through your familiar's eyes:

> While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, you can communicate with it telepathically. Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses that the familiar has. During this time, you are deaf and blind with regard to your own senses.

Another option, assuming you could get hold of one, would be a [*gem of seeing*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Gem%20of%20Seeing#h-Gem%20of%20Seeing) which gives you truesight for a short time. Your character can eventually get the [*true seeing*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/True%20Seeing#h-True%20Seeing) spell as well.

Comment: You could also gain access to Find Familiar using the Magic Initiate feat (this is apparently how the character of [Shakaste](https://criticalrole.fandom.com/wiki/Shak%C3%A4ste) from CR has access to the spell; though frustratingly not mentioned on the page, he's meant to be blind and uses his familiar to see, apparently in his case without requiring use of an action or affecting his hearing).

Comment: I don't think a Gem of Seeing would work, since you need to peer through the gem to gain truesight, which a blind character cannot do. It's not clear that *True Seeing* would work either, e.g. see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72157/can-you-blind-a-demilich-creature-that-has-truesight).

Answer (score 8):

### The *Ersatz Eye*

The [*Ersatz Eye*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ersatz-eye) (XGtE, page 137) grants vision when placed in the socket of a missing eye - the perfect Father's Day gift for a Vecna cultist or a Treasure Island pirate.

If vision in only one eye is still too much, perhaps your DM would agree to further nerf it in one of the following ways:

- It's defective, and vision past 15 feet is just fuzzy blobs of color.
- It's defective, and only gives a narrow slice of normal vision, like you were looking through a paper towel tube.
- It's defective, and unexpectedly ceases to work for anywhere from a minute to an hour for no obvious reason (like a radio with a loose connection). DM determines when it fails.
- It's too small for the socket and prone to popping out unexpectedly.
- It's defective, and stops working after an hour of use.
- It's got a sharp edge making it uncomfortable to wear for more than a few minutes at a time, so it gets used very sparingly. (Sort of like contact lenses in the 1970s.)
- The iris is an unusual color or the pupil is an inhuman shape. DM can determine what positive or negative effect this has.

Also: since this is for a low-level character with limited funds, having it be defective makes it more likely it's received as a gift or a tip for some service done. Alternately it could be taken from a defeated bandit of some sort who was also missing an eye (An Ersatz Eye made for a goblin could be pretty hammered and have most of the mentioned flaws).

Answer (score -2):

[*Regenerate*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Regenerate#content) is a Spell built explicitly for this purpose and has no costly material components. It is known by every Druid or Cleric capable of casting 7th level spells. A proper Religion or Nature check to know this in the game world and you now have reason to quest to find one.

Your character should have faith in a world where the priest of gods hand out miraculous proof of their existence on the daily basis. You should therefore start climbing the ecclesiastical hierarchy of your religion, being pious, humble and generous with your tithing, and be ready to accept a [*Geas*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Geas#content) to perform a quest for the Cleric as the price for what basically cost the Cleric a 5th and 7th level spell slot for otherwise free adventurer labor.

If that's denied because you're being a proactive player in a railroad universe where the DM inflict conditions outside the rules and then deny the rules that allow them being addressed, your alternative which is better than Magic Initiate is *Find Familiar* gained from the Ritual Caster Feat as *Find Familiar* is a Ritual, and as an added bonus you gain the ability to cast Rituals. Or have a discussion with the DM or find a different DM if you don't feel up to an uncomfortable discussion.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Firstly, it is stated in the question that magical healing, which presumably includes *regenerate*, does not work and that it so by the players design. Secondly, *regenerate* would provide a permanent fix to the problem rather than a temporary as asked for. Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Thirdly, I'm not sure I manage to follow your second and third paragraphs well enough to see their merit, and I think some of the language could be seen as somewhat (passive) aggressive. You may wish to restructure and soften the language a bit (maybe use shorter sentences?) otherwise it could attract (more) downvotes.

Comment: Hello, many tables have different play styles, and OP explicitly stated that the blindness is the desired RP condition and that this solution is not what the player is looking for.