# Can a creature under the effect of the True Seeing spell see a creature under the effect of Nondetection inside the area of a Darkness spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, special-senses

As explained in the Q&A [Do Nondetection and Invisibility protect you from True Seeing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80845/do-nondetection-and-invisibility-protect-you-from-true-seeing), the *nondetection* spell would hide an invisible character from being seen by a creature under the effect of the *true seeing* spell (though not natural truesight). I am framing my question with the context that *true seeing* is included among the divination magic that *nondetection* hides creatures from.

**Can someone with the *true seeing* spell cast on them see someone in the area of a *darkness* spell that has *nondetection* cast on them?**

---

To answer this appropriately, I feel an answer must consider this:
[Does the True Seeing spell modify your actual sight, or give you a second sight?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164489/does-the-true-seeing-spell-modify-your-actual-sight-or-give-you-a-second-sight)

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on whether the new sense granted by the truesight spell can be used with the creatures natural sight, or if the use of the creatures natural sight and the use of their newfound sense are mutually exclusive**

The [true seeing](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/True%20Seeing#content) spell gives the creature an additional sense (through the use of divination magic), it reads:

> "For the duration, the creature has truesight."

The [nondetection](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Nondetection#content) spell hides the creature from divination. The creature under the effect of nondetection, therefore, is hidden from the new sense granted to the creature under true seeing.

---

If their natural sense can be used with the truesight granted by divination magic, then the truesight will see through the darkness, and their natural sight will see the visible creature.

On the other hand, if the creature can only use his newfound truesight exclusive to the use of his natural sight, then he will see two things; with his natural sight he will see the area covered by darkness. With his truesight granted by divination magic, he will see no darkness, but the creature under the effect of nondetection will be hidden from this sense.